# IIS Express on Windows 8: error with user NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM

Tags: .net, windows, batch-file, windows-services, iis-express

I have a Windows Service (.NET) that runs a batch file that start IIS Express.
The windows service runs as SYSTEM user.

Batch file

```
CD "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express"
iisexpress /config:"C:\...\IIS Express config\x64_applicationhost.config"
```

With OS <= Win7: all good. IIS Express works perfectly.

Now the same windows service + IIS express must run on Win 8.1 and Win 2012 server.
The windows service is fine, it can run the batch file and IIS Express starts. But when I browse the .NET web application I get this error:

```
The current identity (NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM) does not have write access to 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files'
```

The window service runs the batch file as follows:

```
Dim processInfo As ProcessStartInfo
processInfo = New ProcessStartInfo("C:\...\IISExpressStart.bat")
processInfo.CreateNoWindow = False
Process.Start(processInfo)
```

My question is:
how can I run IIS express as NETWORK SERVICE from a batch file?
Does it depends on how I start IIS express or on IIS express configuration?
Any idea?

It seems IIS Express inherits the service's user. Changing the service's user is not really an option.

Comment: Maybe just a problem because a missing "aspnet_regiis"

Comment: If you wish to add an answer, please do. But please do not put answers into the question. I rolled back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by a missing aspnet_regiis:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis -ga "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"
```